# SQL Server - CROSS DEPENDENCIES DATABASES

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I'm able to pull cross databases dependencies but when the referencedDB is DIFFERENT DATABASE then I'm able to fetch the referenced object but not referenced OBJECT TYPE (e.g user_table,stored procedure etc..,)

Is there any way to find the OBJECT TYPE of referencedDB object?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The system views (e.g., sys.object) are views, effectively under the schema sys.

So you should be able to get object types etc from statements like

```
SELECT type_desc
FROM yourOtherDatabaseName.sys.Objects
WHERE name = 'yourObjectToCheck'
```

Note - Information_schema is also similar - you can use them like

```
SELECT TOP 10 * from
yourOtherDatabaseName.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.tables
```